# How can set the order of name servers in LINUX?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, postfix, nameserver, internal-dns

This question is in context with the DNS queries by postfix MTA in Ubuntu OS. The issue I am facing is that I have two name servers one internal and one external. External DNS name server is added in the hope if the internal gives some issue the server can fallback to external. To ensure it I placed the external DNS below the internal one in the netplan files. But contrary to my believe the queries are done to any nameserver (the order looks random to me). I want to ask:

If this is expected behavior ?

How and if I can configure the server to follow the behavior I want?

If I want to add additional internal internal server to distribute the load. First will it help and second is load balancing from the client is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't configure DNS in Postfix itself and I don't think you could either. Postfix uses the system resolver libraries and typically behaves the same as the rest of your system does with regard to DNS resolution.

On a modern Ubuntu releases DNS resolution is typically implemented via [systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-resolved.service.html).

That allows you to use the [`FallbackDNS=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html#FallbackDNS=) and [`DNS=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html#DNS=) options to make the distinction between a first choice and back-up DNS server(s) in the [`resolved.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html) configuration file(s).

Comment: If I configure the DNS in a particular order (in space separated format) in DNS field in systemd-resolved file will it honor the order?

Comment: By not using systemd-resolved but a legacy format of [`etc/resolv.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) you could get the traditional behaviour : *`nameserver Name server IP address`
Internet address of a name server that the resolver should query, either an IPv4 address (in dot notation), or an IPv6 address in colon (and possibly dot) notation as per RFC 2373. Up to MAXNS (currently 3) name servers may be listed, one per keyword. **If there are multiple servers, the resolver library queries them in the order listed** .* - But that is probably not what you should want.

Comment: But otherwise, use the fallbackDNS to point out what the fallback should be and the resolved  will use all `DNS` entries as equivalent use them all

Comment: Are you sure this is how fallback DNS works? I read from somewhere that this list is indeed used when no other DNS resolver is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you configure the internal DNS server to resolve internal addresses and forward all requests for other domains to an external DNS server. That way you only need to configure one DNS server and you don't even have to worry about a wrong order.